# Where are the ASP.NET core symbols hosted?

Tags: asp.net-core

Have the .NET / ASP.NET core symbols been hosted anywhere yet?  They would be helpful in debugging and learning.

Comment: maybe this can help you : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015/

Answer (score 1):

To debug Asp.Net Core, I followed the article sbouaked is mentionning, got the source from Git, and it's working perfectly. Didn't find a way to get only the symbols.